# ARBodyTrackingConfiguration - CPU jump to 200%

Tags: arkit, coreml, realitykit

I have an app that uses ARKit with RealityKit using ARBodyTrackingConfiguration. I also perform CoreML detections on CVPixelBuffers from ARFrame.

It worked perfectly without issues until around iOS 14.5. Since then if I run AR experience for longer than 20-30s with body detection and CoreML processing detections at the same time, I get big jump in CPU usage (from 80-100% to around 200-220%) which lasts for few seconds and produce lagging/stuttering video footage on device screen.

What I've tried:

- I checked for memory leaks in instruments and can't find anything wrong there. If I disable either body detection or CoreML processing, the issue disappears.
- I tried putting CoreML processing on .utility qos (which gives less detections per second) but it still didn't help.
- I never process more than one frame in CoreML (I check if previous processing was finished).
- It's not thermal issue because it appears even if I start the phone after night of not using it, it still appears after around 20-30s

Here is the screenshot from Debug Navigator
[image]

Comment: Have you tried perhaps changed your build optimization settings? That can make a big difference in some cases. Or perhaps you are holding onto on of the CVPixelBuffers and not releasing it's contents.

Comment: Look like you have problem with Multithreading, some async operations not finished when you starting new operations.